# Building proper link with spaces

Tags: python

I have the following code in Python:

```
linkHTML = "<a href=\"page?q=%s\">click here</a>" % strLink
```

The problem is that when strLink has spaces in it the link shows up as

```
<a href="page?q=with space">click here</a>
```

I can use strLink.replace(" ","+")

But I am sure there are other characters which can cause errors. I tried using

```
urllib.quote(strLink)
```

But it doesn't seem to help.

Thanks!
Joel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you use the urllib.quote_plus(string[, safe]) to replace spaces with plus sign.

```
urllib.quote_plus(string[, safe])
```

> Like quote(), but also replaces spaces
>   by plus signs, as required for quoting
>   HTML form values when building up a
>   query string to go into a URL. Plus
>   signs in the original string are
>   escaped unless they are included in
>   safe. It also does not have safe
>   default to '/'.

from http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote_plus

Ideally you'd be using the urllib.urlencode function and passing it a sequence of key/value pairs like {["q","with space"],["s","with space & other"]} etc.

Answer (score 1):

As well as `quote_plus`(*), you also need to HTML-encode any text you output to HTML. Otherwise `<` and `&` symbols will be markup, with potential security consequences. (OK, you're not going to get `<` in a URL, but you definitely are going to get `&`, so just one parameter name that matches an HTML entity name and your string's messed up.

```
html= '<a href="page?q=%s">click here</a>' % cgi.escape(urllib.quote_plus(q))
```

*: actually plain old `quote` is fine too; I don't know what wasn't working for you, but it is a perfectly good way of URL-encoding strings. It converts spaces to `%20` which is also valid, and valid in path parts too. `quote_plus` is optimal for generating query strings, but otherwise, when in doubt, `quote` is safest.